# How to show to handle enums in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I like to keep the values for all of these in a central place. For example, I might have an enum that looks like this:

```
$mobies = [
    'APPLE' => "Apple",
    'SUM' => "Sumsung",
    'LG' => "LG",
];
```

Which I want to use in both my view/template:

migrate table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id;
    $table->enum('mobiles',['apple','sumsung','lg']);
    ...
});
```

config/enums.php

```
<?php

return [
    'mobiles' => [
        'APPLE' => "Apple",
        'SUM' => "Sumsung",
        'LG' => "LG",
    ];
];
```

index.blade.php

```
{{ config('enums.reportableTitle') }}
```

How to show in a blade when it saves in the database.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from `config/enums.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'mobiles' => [
        'APPLE' => "Apple",
        'SUM' => "Sumsung",
        'LG' => "LG",
    ]
];
```

You can reuse it anywhere with config helper `config('enums.mobiles')`

You can use it in your migration table by retrieving only its value with `array_values()`

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id;
    $table->enum('mobiles', array_values(config('enums.mobiles')));
    ...
});
```

In your blade file you can also use config helper like

```
{{ config('enums.mobiles')['APPLE'] }}
```