# Laravel - how to handle ENUMs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Considering "enums", for instance:

- **gender**: male, female
- **marital status**: Single, Married, Separated, Divorced, Widowed

What is the best way to work with them in Models in a Laravel application? How to retrieve the list of possibilities and how to store them?

---

I tried using a table/model named "parameters". Simplifying, consider two tables:

**people**

```
|-----|-------|---------|----------------|
| id  | name  | gender  | marital_status |
|-----|-------|---------|----------------|
|  1  | Clark |    1    |       4        |
|  2  | Bruce |    1    |       3        |
|  3  | Diana |    2    |       3        |
|  4  | Louis |    2    |       4        |
|-----|-------|---------|----------------|
```

**parameters** (I called like this, but it could be "domains", "enums", "lists", etc).

```
|----|----------------|---------|
| id | type           | name    |
|----|----------------|---------|
|  1 | gender         | Male    |
|  2 | gender         | Female  |
|  3 | marital_status | Single  |
|  4 | marital_status | Married |
|----|----------------|---------|
```

But here I faced some doubts: how to create relationship between these models on Laravel, considering that just part of *parameters* table can be used on relationship? I.e. I shouldn't be able to set `$person->gender = 3;`

Maybe, the ideal is to create a table for each "type of parameter", but actually, there are lots of parameter types.

Other approach is to hard code the enums as config options, as presented in [How to show to handle enums in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351117/how-to-show-to-handle-enums-in-laravel).

**So, what is the best way to work with them in a Laravel application?**

Comment: If you take the table approach is enum should be a separate table so you can have strict foreign key constraints on them

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using lookup tables where appropriate. For tables where data doesn’t change frequently consider using a fast cache such as Redis. A generic lookup table is considered a code smell.

Answer (score -2):

A static information like gender and marital status should not saved in database, something like this are saved in config files. you could add a new config file to `config` directory and call it for example `general.php` then you could save this info in it, like:

```
<?php

return [

    'gender' => [
        'male',
        'female'
    ],

    'marital_status' => [
        'Single',
        'Married',
        'Separated',
        'Divorced',
        'Widowed'
    ]
];
```

And then after running `php artisan config:cache` you could call it when you want as `config('general.gender')`.

Also, you could handle them in your migration file as:

```
$table->enum('gender', config('general.gender'));
```

Finally, as a validation rule you could do:

```
'field' => 'in:' . implode(',', config('general.gender')),
```

Comment: The data should be accessible and make sense when accessed from different application codes, not just when using a specific laravel codebase with the correct config file/s.